# How to pass a variable to full calendar event?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

this is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dates = "{title  : 'event1',start  : '2018-07-10'},{title  : 'event2',start  : '2010-07-18'}";

  dates = JSON.parse(dates);
  alert(dates);

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: 450,
    defaultView: 'month',
    events: dates
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css" />
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

I need to pass the dates variable to the full calendar event. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid, as it's just a list of objects with no link between them. You can use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON strings. This is causing you to get an error when you try and parse it because you can't change a series of objects into a single variable. Your field names and values also need to be double-quoted, so you need to wrap your string in single-quotes. Besides that fullCalendar requires an *array* of events, and this is a valid thing to parse into a variable.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var dates = '[{"title": "event1", "start": "2018-07-10"},{"title": "event2","start": "2010-07-18"}]';
  dates = JSON.parse(dates);

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: 450,
    defaultView: 'month',
    events: dates
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css" />
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Alternatively, you could build a JavaScript object directly, if you're using JavaScript to generate the event data:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var dates = [{"title": "event1", "start": "2018-07-10"},{"title": "event2","start": "2010-07-18"}];

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: 450,
    defaultView: 'month',
    events: dates
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css" />
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass event data as an array. At the moment, you're passing an object. Instead of writing your dates in a string, just write the array manually into the `events` property of the constructor as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        height: 450,
        defaultView: 'month',
        events: [
            {
                title: 'event1',
                start: '2018-07-10'
            },
            {
                title: 'event2',
                start: '2010-07-18'
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

You can read more about adding events in the [FullCalendar docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array).

Alternatively, if you *have* to use the `JSON.parse()`, simply wrap the string in square brackets:

```
var dates = JSON.parse('[{"title": "event1","start": "2018-07-10"},{"title": "event2","start": "2010-07-18"}]');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I am generating the event dates in the code itself. so how to achieve that?

Comment: Not sure I understand? Are you pulling in the string from a database or similar?

Comment: yes. I need to get the event dates from the database.

Comment: @DhanushkaWeerasinghe "I am generating the event dates in the code itself" that doesn't require you to generate them as a string. In fact it would be much more robust to make an array of objects directly if you're doing that task using JavaScript.

Comment: So can you suggest a way to this? I need to get the event dates from the database